# Multi-Term Wildcard queries in Lucene?

Tags: php, zend-framework, full-text-search, lucene

I'm using Zend_Search_Lucene, the PHP port of Java Lucene. I currently have some code that will build a search query based on an array of strings, finding results for which at least one index field matches each of the strings submitted. Simplified, it looks like this:

(Note: $words is an array constructed from user input.)

```
$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
foreach ($words as $word) {
  $term1 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term($word, $fieldname1);
  $term2 = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_term($word, $fieldname2);
  $multiq = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm();
  $multiq->addTerm($term1);
  $multiq->addTerm($term2);
  $query->addSubquery($multiq, true);
}
$hits = $index->find($query);
```

What I would *like* to do is replace **$word** with **($word . '*')** — appending an asterisk to the end of each word, turning it into a wildcard term.

But then, $multiq would have to be a **Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Wildcard** instead of a **Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_MultiTerm**, and I don't think I would still be able to add multiple Index_Terms to each **$multiq**.

Is there a way to construct a query that's both a Wildcard and a MultiTerm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the way you're hoping to achieve it, unfortunately:

> Lucene supports single and multiple
>   character wildcard searches within
>   single terms (but not within phrase
>   queries).

and even if it were possible, would probably not be a good idea:

> Wildcard, range and fuzzy search
>   queries may match too many terms. It
>   may cause incredible search
>   performance downgrade.

I imagine the way to go if you insist on multiple wildcard terms, would be two execute two separate searches, one for each wildcarded term, and bundle the results together.